# Does Apache Crunch come with the Hadoop MapReduce API?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-crunch

When you download Apache Crunch from their website (it comes as source code), it comes without the related MapReduce classes it's based on. Two questions:

1- How is this possible? Apache Crunch is an abstraction on top of MapReduce. How come it isn't packaged with the MapReduce classes?

2- What do I need to do to develop using Apache Crunch? Do I need to download Crunch and MapReduce separately? If so, how can I know which MapReduce version I need to match the Crunch version?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for Mapreduce classes within Apache Crunch

I did performed a random check and none of those classes seem to extend hadoop classes and rather methioned like below

Static functions for working with legacy Mappers and Reducers that live under the org.apache.hadoop.mapred.* package as part of Crunch pipelines.

Are you using version 0.6 or earlier ?